# Dynamically edit Nginx for pointing custom cname to application

Tags: dynamic, nginx, virtualhost, httpserver

I have a Play 2 application running on domain 'example.com' which allows user to register their page like **john.example.com**. I also want them to create a CNAME record to point their personal domain to his page, ex **my.john.com -> john.example.com**. How can I edit Nginx programmably to allow this?

I am using nginx 1.4.3.